# Does this equation E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y] always apply?

Tags: statistics

I am a student studying statistics and I have some questions about $E(X)$.

Am I right in understanding that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ for every random variable $X$ and $Y$, but $V[X+Y]=V[X]+V[Y]$ only when $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Thank you for your time!

+) I noticed that the comments below refer to independence and uncorrelation as different concepts, but I'm not exactly sure how:(  Could someone please elaborate??

Comment: Both assertions are essentially correct, though $V[X+Y]=V[X]+V[Y]$ holds if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are *uncorrelated*, which is a **weaker** condition than independence.

Comment: Independence is a sufficient but not necessary condition for the variance relationship you wrote. So "only when" is not correct. The rest is fine.

Comment: "Only when" may be bad phrasing. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $V(X+Y)=V(X)+V(Y)$, but $V(X+Y)=V(X)+V(Y)$ does not imply independence. Of course, typically, we can conclude $V(X+Y)=V(X)+V(Y)$ in a proof because we know that the random variables are independent, but formally, it is not necessary.

Comment: As an exercise, I would suggest you create a counterexample of two non independent random variables, such that the variance of their sum is equal to the sum of their variances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For expectations, the result holds provided $E[X],\,E[Y]$ exist, either both finite or not some permutation of $\infty,\,-\infty$ (since $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminant form).

The manipulation$$V[X+Y]=\operatorname{Cov}[X+Y,\,X+Y]=V[X]+V[Y]+2\operatorname{Cov}(X,\,Y)$$requires each term to exist, again with indeterminate-form concerns if multiple terms are infinite. (If $V[X],\,V[Y]$ are both finite we're fine, since by Cauchy-Schwarz $|\operatorname{Cov}(X,\,Y)|\le\sqrt{V[X]V[Y]}$.) The zero-covariance condition is that $X,\,Y$ are uncorrelated, which demands much less than independence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, expectation is linear so $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$. However $V[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$
Which in our case is:
$V[X+Y]=E[(X+Y)^2]-E[X+Y]^2=E[X^2]+2E[XY]+E[Y^2]-E[X+Y]\cdot E[X+Y]$
  and as you cannot always guarantee that $E[X\cdot Y]=E[X]\cdot E[Y]$, variance is not linear.

(A case where you could guarantee $E[X\cdot Y]=E[X]\cdot E[Y]$ is when $X$ and $Y$ are independent)

Comment: You're statement on independence is not correct. Variance of the sum can equal the sum of the variances even if the two random variables are not independent!

Comment: Your absolutely correct it can, I simply said you cannot guarantee it

Comment: Suppose I said "you cannot guarantee a number is even unless it's a multiple of four". Would you consider it a correct sentence?

Comment: And by the way, linearity is another matter. Take two indipendent random variables $X$ and $Y$ and consider the variable $Z = X-Y$. Linearity would imply the variance of $Z$ being the difference of the corresponding variances, which is false.